# Primefaces 500 Error on starting server

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm not sure what I've done, but after a recent build on the Server I'm getting this error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:26)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:28)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:612)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:907)
```

Anyone seen this before or any idea what might have caused it?

Comment: Please provide some more details. Is this error incredibly broken out all of a sudden without any change(s) to previous successful builds?

Comment: *"Anyone seen this before"*, just copypaste the exception and the 1st line of the stack trace into a search engine.

Comment: Yeah I've been doing that. Can't find anything that relates. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Most examples seem to relate to upgrading Primefaces. I've not upgraded Primefaces.